# Objective-C NS_ENUM not recognized in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I am using the google VR SDK external framework in my swift project.

In my Bridging-Header.h I am importing the framework header

```
#import "GVRCardboardView.h"
```

In GVRCardboardView.h there is this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GVRUserEvent) {
  kGVRUserEventBackButton,
  kGVRUserEventTilt,
  kGVRUserEventTrigger,
};
```

In my swift code

```
@objc func cardboardView(_ cardboardView: GVRCardboardView!, didFire event: GVRUserEvent) {

        switch (event) {
        case kGVRUserEventBackButton:
            print("User pressed back button");
            break;
        case GVRUserEvent.kGVRUserEventTilt:
           print("User performed tilt action");
            break;

        case .kGVRUserEventTrigger:
            print("User performed trigger action");
            break;
        }
}
```

But I get compiler errors.  You can see I'm trying three different ways to access the enum values in my switch case, and they all give errors. First,

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'kGVRUserEventTilt'
```

When I searched other similar questions online, I saw the solution was to include the name of the enum, like you see in the second case of my switch statement.  But that gives me this error:

```
Type 'GVRUserEvent' has no member 'kGVRUserEventTilt'
```

And the third case gives this:

```
Pattern cannot match values of type 'GVRUserEvent'
```

Anyone know why?  It recognizes GVRUserEvent as something -- I don't get errors in the argument line.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It should be `case .backButton:` ... just try autocompletion.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I forgot that Swift does that automatic name conversion thing.